# Using sklearn models as input to deep learning models

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

Keras gives me a way to use my deep learning models with sklearn(The keras wrapper for sklearn), but I need the same thing the **other way around**.

I want to create an ensemble of several already trained sklearn models by feeding their output to the input layer of a deep learning classifier(to be trained)

Can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? You cannot optimise a Machine Learning model together with Deep Learning because the `sklearn` models do not provide gradient information in order to apply gradient descent...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to chain an scikit-learn estimator and a Keras estimator ?

Comment: I want to create an ensemble of several already trained sklearn models by feeding their output to the input layer of a deep learning classifier(to be trained). sorry if Im not expressing the question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably explore Stacking : http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/

What happens is that when we are doing cross validation, we can combine combine the out of fold predictions to regenerate the training data.

For example, if you 1000 data points and you use 5 folds to evaluate, you will have 5 different validation sets of length 200. Combining all the predictions obtained on this set will essentially give you a new feature of length 1000, hence a new feature.
Similarly  by training more models, you can get 3-4 features corresponding to predictions from 3-4 models.

Finally you can stack these features with any model of your choice, you can even use a deep neural network.